# Concatenate macro, string and counter

Tags: macros, tex-core, strings

I'm trying the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{testcounter}
\def\teststring{begin}

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{testcounter}

\def\newstring{\expandafter\string\csname\teststring-middle-\thetestcounter\endcsname}

\thetestcounter

\teststring

\newstring

\end{document}
```

And the result is the following:

[image]

So, I don't know where the " comes from. The above example is just a demo. The concatenated string \newstring´´ will later be used inside a \label command.

Any hints are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

The `"` is just the character `\`  printed using OT1 encoding, try with

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

To see a `\`

So it really is `\` and can be used as such in internal command names.

Note however it would generally not be safe to use such a string as the argument to `\label` as while the `\` is inert while being written out to the aux file it will be interpreted as the escape character while the aux file is read.

Comment: Sorry David, I forgot to mention that I just want the string concatenated and no \ at the begin. You're right: I don't want the backslash inside the \label.

Comment: @aronadaal in that case just remove the `\expandafter\string\csname` and `\endcsname` and possibly use `\edef` instead of `\def`, depending on what you want.

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
\string\foo
```

the control sequence name is transformed into a list of characters (all having character code 12, except for possible spaces that keep category code 10) *preceded* by the character having the same ASCII code as the current value of `\escapechar` (usually 92, that is, the backslash).

When you do `\expandafter\string\csname<code>\endcsname`, you first make a token out of the full expansion of `<code>` and then represent it as before; in your example you get

```
\begin-middle-1
```

as a string of characters.

What you probably want is

```
\edef\newstring{\teststring-middle-\thetestcounter}
```

that does the full expansion as well, but doesn't make a control sequence name out of it.